# Error: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[RouterLinkWithHref -> Router]: (NullInjectorError: No provider for Router!)

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I am preparing unit test case for AppComponent which have router as a injected dependency and have included RouterTestingModule in my test bed. But still getting a weird error. Please find the error log shown below:

```
Error: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[RouterLinkWithHref -> Router]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[RouterLinkWithHref -> Router]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for Router!
```

> error properties: Object({ ngTempTokenPath: null, ngTokenPath: [
>   'RouterLinkWithHref', Function ], ngDebugContext: DebugContext_({
>   view: Object({ def: Object({ factory: Function, nodeFlags: 671753,
>   rootNodeFlags: 1, nodeMatchedQueries: 0, flags: 0, nodes: [ Object({
>   nodeIndex: 0, parent: null, renderParent: null, bindingIndex: 0,
>   outputIndex: 0, checkIndex: 0, flags: 1, childFlags: 671753,
>   directChildFlags: 1, childMatchedQueries: 0, matchedQueries: Object({ 
>   }), matchedQueryIds: 0, references: Object({  }), ngContentIndex:
>   null, childCount: 10, bindings: [ Object({ flags: 8, ns: '', name:
>   'className', nonMinifiedName: 'className', securityContext: 0, suffix:
>   undefined }) ], bindingFlags: 8, outputs: [  ], element: Object({ ns:
>   '', name: 'nav', attrs: [ Array ], template: null, componentProvider:
>   null, componentView: null, componentRendererType: null,
>   publicProviders: null({  }), allProviders: null({  }), handleEvent:
>   Function }), provider: null, text: null, query: null, ngContent: null
>   }), Object({  ... Error:
>   StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[RouterLinkWithHref -> Router]: 
>   StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[RouterLinkWithHref -> Router]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for Router!
>       at NullInjector.get (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:1360:19)
>       at resolveToken (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:1598:24)
>       at tryResolveToken (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:1542:16)
>       at StaticInjector.get (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:1439:20)
>       at resolveToken (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:1598:24)
>       at tryResolveToken (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:1542:16)
>       at StaticInjector.get (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:1439:20)
>       at resolveNgModuleDep (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:8667:29)
>       at NgModuleRef_.get (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:9355:16)
>       at resolveDep (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:9720:45)

Please help. I have already tried removing router links from my template.

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [
      AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
      CoreModule.forRoot(),
      RouterTestingModule.withRoutes(routes),
    ],
    providers: [
      {provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/'},
    ]
}
```

Comment: Just in case, try to create component like `TestBed.overrideComponent(AppComponent, { set: { template: '' }}).createComponent(AppComponent);` and check whether that error stays or not.

Comment: So have you tried that?

Comment: Let me try it and see if it works.

Comment: This solution didn't work

Comment: Ok, can you add the listing of CoreModule, please?

Comment: Thanks, i was able to resolve issues by correcting versions of dependencies

Answer (score 34):

May I know if you have imported `RouterTestingModule`? You should import it this way:

`import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';`

Also, what is `routes` in your `RouterTestingModule.withRoutes(routes)`? Here is a sample of how you can import RouterTestingModule into your Testbed.

```js
beforeEach(async(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [
      HttpClientTestingModule,
      RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([]),
    ],
    declarations: [
      SomeComponent,
    ],
    providers: [
      SampleService,
    ],

  })
    .compileComponents()
}))
```

Comment: In which file we should update inOrder to resolve this issue

Comment: @MohanGopi it should be in your test/spec file that requires the usage of mocked routers

Answer (score -2):

I was able to resolve this issue. While modifying test cases i updated version of @types/jasmine to resolve some issue and updated some other dependencies as well. In the background my application also broke due to that. So, i re-forked the repository and then updated required dependencies only. Now code is working fine.